# Is it possible to run multiple update statements separated by semi colon in mysql at once?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-instances

I have a text file with 67,000 rows and each row is an update statement.

is it possible to execute all of the update statements at once? or what tool can I use to do this in MySQL?

The data or the columns being updated changes for most of them.

Here are a couple of samples  that have for the update.

```
UPDATE emailTbl SET  CC="", BCC="", recipient_new="someone@domain.com" WHERE docid=0000000139;        
UPDATE emailTbl SET  CC="", BCC="", recipient_new="someone2@domain.com" WHERE docid=0000000362;        
UPDATE emailTbl SET sender_new="aperson@domain.com", CC="", BCC="", recipient_new="anotheruser@domain.com" WHERE docid=0000004313;
```

Comment: If you're sure there are no syntax errors in your text file, just running "mysql mydatabase < file.txt" from the command line should work; possibly you have to specify the -h, -u and -p flags for hostname, username and password as well.

Comment: the syntax is correct because if I run the statements one at a time they work. I am really sorry about not knowing so much about MySQL. I am kind of new at this. I would really like if you could point me to a sample.

Comment: Whether or not you can do this is client-dependent. If you use the mysql command line client, then yes you may execute multiples as mentioned in an earlier comment. If you were using certain APIs in programming languages, many don't support multiple delimited statements.

Comment: No APIs involved. I need to do this right from MySQL GUI or from the command line.

Comment: Like Michael said it is client dependent. Provide more details on how you are trying to run the commands such as from the command line terminal like the example Guntram gave or from some other application or code like java, and maybe we can give you more help.

Comment: Use single quotes `'` for string literals. If you insist on using double-quotes, `"` ensure that `ANSI_QUOTES` is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say whether you are using an InnoDB or a MyISAM table. It matters, because InnoDB supports transactions.  You can get this to run much faster on InnoDB by adding an occasional transaction line to your text file.

The file should ideally look like this:

```
  START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE emailTbl SET  CC="", BCC="", recipient_new="someone@domain.com" WHERE docid=0000000139;
  UPDATE emailTbl SET blah blah blah;
  UPDATE emailTbl SET blah blah blah;
  ...97 more UPDATE lines ... 
  COMMIT;
  START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE emailTbl SET blah blah blah;
  ...99 more UPDATE lines ... 
  COMMIT;
  START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE emailTbl SET blah blah blah;
  ...99 more UPDATE lines ... 
  COMMIT;
```

In other words, begin your file with `START TRANSACTION;`.  End it with `COMMIT;`. Every hundred lines or so insert these two lines to finish up one transaction and start another.

```
  COMMIT;
  START TRANSACTION;
```

If you don't do this, your command line `mysql` client will run in autocommit mode, which will make it take a lot longer to chew through all these updates; it will do a commit for each row.

If you run `mysql` with autocommit mode turned off, it will try to do all 67 kilorows in a single transaction. You may fill up your server's commit buffer RAM.

Comment: It is giving me the following error mysql> dwdata < c:\Update\files2.sql;
ERROR:
Unknown command '\U'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\f'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dwdat
a < c:\Update\files2.sql' at line 1

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I followed your instructions and its all done!

Answer (score 1):

This is supported using the `mysql` command-line tool.

The statements are executed sequentially. I do not know of any tools that do this in parallel, nor am I sure that's a good idea.

Comment: It's a really bad idea, for example, if there's a chance some of the updates would apply to rows that were updated earlier in the script.